# email does not contain any text

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I'm using following code to send an email:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add("ToEmail");
    msg.From = new MailAddress("From Email", "Display Name", Encoding.UTF8);
    msg.Subject = "This is a simple test";
    msg.Body = "This is test";
    msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Display name",         "password");
    client.Port = 465;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        client.SendAsync("From Email", "", msg.Subject, msg.Body, "test message1");
        MessageBox.Show("Sent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The code itself seems to work fine. Anyway, I am not receiving any text inside the email, although text for the body was provided.

This means I'm getting an empty email sent.

Comment: why not `client.SendAsync(msg,"");` ?

Comment: why not to use simple `client.send();` method? @Anirudha @AngelOfDeath

Comment: try `client.send(msg)`

Comment: Without a recipient it stays useless whatever send method is used. You need to set a recipient!

Comment: see the `msg.To.Add("ToEmail");` its already added @Ralf

Comment: Not in the shown SendAsync call. But you are right i missed it in his MailMessage setup code :(

Comment: You are (probably incorrectly) using the 5-argument `SendAsync` call, instead of the 4-argument version.  The argument you think is the message is being used as the `UserToken` which won't do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

It appears send async expects a message object as it's first argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

this example from Microsoft shows an exact demonstration which varies from your code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx